# Using class as a phonebook dictionary

Tags: class, dictionary, methods, init

```
class PhoneBook:

    def __init__(self):
        self.contacts = {}

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.contacts)

    def add(self, name, mobile=None, office=None, email=None):
        self.contacts["Name"] = name
        self.contacts["Mobile"] = mobile
        self.contacts["Office"] = office
        self.contacts["Email"] = email

obj = PhoneBook()
obj.add("Kim", office="1234567", email="kim@company.com")
obj.add("Park", office="2345678", email="park@company.com")
print(obj)
```

I tried to make PhoneBook class to add up the dictionary lists as I put .add method to the class variable but every time the class variable calls the PhoneBook() class, the dictionary initialization occurs and only the last data remains in the dictionary(I suppose :S)

Is there any way to solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, you're using the same dictionary key `"Name"` to store your contacts. Instead, put real name as a key to dictionary and this key will hold another dictionary. For example:

```py
import pprint


class PhoneBook:
    def __init__(self):
        self.contacts = {}

    def __str__(self):
        return pprint.pformat(self.contacts, width=30)

    def add(self, name, mobile=None, office=None, email=None):
        self.contacts[name] = {
            "Mobile": mobile,
            "Office": office,
            "Email": email,
        }


obj = PhoneBook()
obj.add("Kim", office="1234567", email="kim@company.com")
obj.add("Park", office="2345678", email="park@company.com")
print(obj)
```

Prints:

```py
{'Kim': {'Email': 'kim@company.com',
         'Mobile': None,
         'Office': '1234567'},
 'Park': {'Email': 'park@company.com',
          'Mobile': None,
          'Office': '2345678'}}
```